# Getting AJAX results from ASP.Net service for select2 control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm trying to implement the Select2 control by pulling information from an ASP.Net Webservice (webforms). I've placed a break point in my server code and the method is getting called and returning information but the select2 control is never displaying the information and **no** console errors are being reported (just the fact that the service was hit and returned). Here's all of the information:

C# Webservice (ListVar is a class that has two string properties of **Value** and **Text**):

```
public List<ListVar> SearchUsers(string searchText, string additionalFilter)
{
    return WebUserManager.SearchWebUsers(searchText, Boolean.Parse(additionalFilter));
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#O_M_aclUser_hfMain').select2({
        ajax: {
            cache: true,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:54780/Services/Utilities.asmx/SearchUsers',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    searchText: term,
                    additionalFilter: $('#O_M_aclUser_hfAddFil').val()
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                alert('test1');
                return { results: data.d };
            }
        },
        formatResult: FormatResults,
        formatSelection: FormatResults,
        dropdownCssClass: 'autoCompleteSelect2',
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });
});

function FormatResults(result) {
    var markup = '<div class="AutoCompleteResult" entityValue="' + result.Value + '">';
    markup += result.Text;
    markup += '</div>';

    return markup;
}
```

Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfListVar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ListVar>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <Text>Miles McGehee</Text>
  </ListVar>
  <ListVar>
    <Value>777</Value>
    <Text>Miles McGehee</Text>
  </ListVar>
</ArrayOfListVar>
```

Why isn't my JS results ajax method getting called? (I never see an alert message)
Why isn't the information being displayed

Comment: Your response is xml not json.

Comment: Is it supposed to be in any particular json format?

Comment: There is no *particular json format*. It depends on what your method returns. In your case, it may be `{"ArrayOfListVar":[{"Value":"1","Text":"Miles McGehee"},{"Value":"777","Text":"Miles McGehee"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your service method so it responds in JSON rather than XML

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<ListVar> SearchUsers(string searchText, string additionalFilter)
{
    return WebUserManager.SearchWebUsers(searchText, Boolean.Parse(additionalFilter));
}
```

There is a particular json format that `select2` expects.  The response needs to be a list `id` and `text` values like so `{"d":[{"id":"1","text":"hello"},{"id":"2","text":"world"}]}`